# Spreadsheetgear deletes Pivot Table on Load: can it ignore certain sheets?

Tags: c#, spreadsheetgear

I use SpreadsheetGear 2012 to update some Data in an Excel Template out of a Database.
This Excel Template is defined by the User and does have some other Sheets defined with Diagrams etc. referring to the Worksheet with the primary Data on it. This works well for normal Charts but now the User configured Pivot Charts in Excel. Once I load the it seems the Pivot Tables are deleted (just show as white area)...
Is there a way with SpreadsheetGear I can only edit one of the Sheets in the Table and write the File (copy the Template) with keeping the Pivot Tables on other Sheets working when opening the File with Excel later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately.  SpreadsheetGear must open files in their entirety to work with them, so there's no way to only access and modify certain sheets while preserving as-is other sheets that might contain Pivot Tables.  Since SpreadsheetGear 2012 does not yet support reading/writing Pivot Tables from/to Excel files, these objects will be dropped upon reading the file into SpreadsheetGear.